# How to get items of bootstrap navbar always inline

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, navbar

I'm starting with Boostrap for a mobile app, I'm using AngularJs and UI-Bootsrap (not JQuery). I'm trying to create a navbar fixed to bottom with 4 glyphicons. The problem is that with a small screen, items are displayed as list, see below :

[image]

In my case, I would to display item always inline in navbar like this :
[image]

see my code here :

```
 <footer>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <!-- c'est par cette syntaxe que nous chargeons des icônes avec Bootstrap -->
                    <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Trash</a></li>
                    <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Camera</a></li>
                    <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted"></span>  Ice cream</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </footer>
```

someone could to tell me how to do it please ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `nav` class

```
   <footer>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                  <!-- c'est par cette syntaxe que nous chargeons des icônes avec Bootstrap -->
                      <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Trash</a></li>
                      <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                      <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Camera</a></li>
                      <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted"></span>  Ice cream</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
      </footer>
```